# Dropping signs while doing integration

Tags: calculus, area

In high school textbooks, we see that while taking square roots, the negative sign is not taken in calculus problems. For example, when asked to find the area bounded by $y^2=-x$ between $-2$ to $-1,$ we do it like this: $$\int_{-2}^{-1} \sqrt{-x} \,\mathrm dx.$$ Why don't we take the $y=-\sqrt{-x}\,?$ In all calculus problems, why is it okay to only the take $\sqrt{a^2}=a$ instead of $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|\,?$

Comment: Which piece of area? From my understanding of the question, $y^2=-x$ becomes two curves $y=\sqrt{-x}$ and $y=-\sqrt{-x}$. Then to find the area between the two curves, I would calculate

$$\int_{-2}^{-1}\left[\sqrt{-x} - (-\sqrt{-x})\right]dx$$

(or multiply your integral result by $2$)

Comment: The standard definition of the symbol $\sqrt{}$ (for real numbers, at least) is that it is the positive root. This means $\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$ is always true, but $\sqrt{a^2} = a$ is not.

Comment: @Dan actually i don't understand whether it answers my question,my doubt is if we have to take $y=\sqrt{-x}$ or $-\sqrt{-x}$ in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

> when asked to find the area bounded by $y^2=-x$ between $-2$ to $-1,$ we do it like this: $$\int_{-2}^{-1} \sqrt{-x} \,\mathrm dx.\tag1$$ Why don't we take the $y=-\sqrt{-x}\,?$

Perhaps you are showing just part of the working, since the required area in this example is obtained by multiplying expression $(1)$ by two, due to the figure's symmetry.

[image]

On the other hand, the **signed area** bounded by $y^2=-x$ between $-2$ to $-1$ *does* involve the $y=-\sqrt{-x}$ portion, and equals $$\int_{-2}^{-1} \sqrt{-x} \,\mathrm dx+\int_{-2}^{-1} -\sqrt{-x} \,\mathrm dx,$$ which equals $0.$

> In all calculus problems, why is it okay to only the take $\sqrt{a^2}=a$ instead of $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|\,?$

This premise is false: the workings above are based on geometry rather than some generic calculus rule.

Answer (score 0):

$y = -\sqrt{x}$ is complex on (-2,-1). you would get $y = -\sqrt{-1}$. What you want is $y=\sqrt{1}$. What you can do is let $z = -x$ then $dz = -dx$ and you get:

$$-\int_2^1 \sqrt{z} dz = \int_1^2 \sqrt{x} dx.$$

For your second question $\sqrt{(-1)^2} = \sqrt{1}=1 = |-1| \neq -1$.

Comment: Actually i meant to ask why we couldn't take $y=-\sqrt{-x}$